# Symfony 3 service depends on unknown quantity of another service. How to implement?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm fairly new to Symfony, but experienced with PHP. Suppose I have a service which needs an unknown quantity of another service. It doesn't make sense to inject it (how many would I inject). I can use the `ContainerAwareInterface` and `ContainerAwareTrait` but I've read that that's [not a good way](https://qafoo.com/blog/057_containeraware_considered_harmful.html).

Slightly contrived example:

```
class ProcessBuilder {
    private $allCommands = [];

    public function build(array $config){
        foreach ($config => $command){
            $this->allCommands[] = $this->getContainer()->get('app.worker.command')->init($command);
        }
    }
}
```

At the point in which I get my `ProcessBuilder` service, I don't know how many items will be in the `$config` array passed into `build()`. Because of how the `Command` class (`app.worker.command` service) works, they cannot share a single instance.

How is the best way to do this? Or do I need to go down the `ContainerAware*` route?

I hope that makes sense and thanks for your help. Sorry if this has been asked before, but I've had a good Google and not come up with anything.

Comment: Maybe [tagged services with a custom compiler pass](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html) is what you need? Or another way could be the [event dispatcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html).

Comment: You should pass command service **factory** instance instead of command service instance. That's a very clean solution. http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html

Comment: @dragoste - Just out of curiosity, how would your factory know which services to use?

Comment: @Cerad the issue is variable amount of instances of a particular service not which service to inject..

Comment: @dragoste I think the issue is how to inject a variable number of command services into some sort of command dispatcher.  But I could easily be wrong.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, sorry for not responding for a while and sorry if the question was misleading. @dragoste is right, I'm wanting a variable number of instances of the same service. I think injecting a factory is exactly what I needed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**You are going the right direction**. Now only right place is missing.

To collect services of certain type, we need to get 1 step ahead. To dependency injection container compilation (that's how services of `EventSubscriber` type or `Voter` type are collected by Symfony.)

You can register service with Extension, and **manipulate them in any way with CompilerPass**.

### Example

Here is [example how to collect all services of type A, and add them to service of type B with setter](https://github.com/Symplify/Symplify/blob/5b9738c28691526199e97e8b1db593f8e9e0d71d/packages/ModularRouting/src/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/AddRouteCollectionProvidersCompilerPass.php#L21-L24).

### Your Case in Compiler Pass

If we convert your code to compiler pass, it would look like this:

**ProcessBuilder.php**

```
class ProcessBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var CommandInterface[]
     */
    private $allCommands = [];

    public function addCommand(CommandInterface $command)  
    {
        $this->allCommands[] = $command
    }
}
```

**AddCommandsToProcessBuilderCompilerPass.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;

final class AddCommandsToProcessBuilderCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder): void
    {
        # using Symfony 3.3+ class name, you can use string name as well
        $processBuilderDefinition = $this->containerBuilder->getDefinition(ProcessBuilder::class);

        foreach ($this->containerBuilder->getDefinitions() as $serviceName => $definition) {
            if (is_subclass_of($definition->getClass(), CommandInterface::class)) {
                $processBuilderDefinition->addMethodCall('addCommand', [new Reference($serviceName)]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AppBundle.php**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

final class AppBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder): void
    {
        $containerBuilder->addCompilerPass(new AddCommandsToProcessBuilderCompilerPass);
    }
}
```

And add your bundle to `AppKernel.php`:

```
final class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        bundles = [];
        $bundles[] = new AppBundle;
    }
}
```

That's complete process to do what you need in clean way in Symfony.